# update statement in spark-sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

is there a way to execute an update statement on sql server table using spark-sql (with scala langage)?

I need to perform the following query:

```
update  MyLog_table
set     Log_FileQueue = xx,
        Log_TotalLine = xx
where   Log_ID = xxx
```

I tried the following syntaxe:

```
 val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort};database=${jdbcDatabase}"
    val Log_FileIn = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, s"(select Log_FileIn from log Where   Log_ID = '${Process1Log_ID}' ) as sq", connectionProperties)
    val newLog_FileIn = Log_FileIn.collectAsList().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")

 spark.sql(s"(select '${newLog_FileIn}' as Log_FileQueue, ${NbLine} as Log_TotalLine where Log_ID = '${newLog_id}')")
  .write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .jdbc(jdbcUrl, "Log", connectionProperties)
```

but it generates the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Log_ID`' given input columns: []; line 1 pos 115;
'Project [test_141001.csv AS Log_FileQueue#290, 5 AS Log_TotalLine#29
```

I tried also to use the "where" method:

```
spark.sql(s"(select '${newLog_FileIn}' as Log_FileQueue, ${NbLine} as Log_TotalLine where Log_ID = '${newLog_id}')")
  .where(s"Log_ID = '${newLog_id}'")
  .write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .jdbc(jdbcUrl, "Log", connectionProperties)
```

but it also does not work. I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Log_ID`' given input columns: [Log_FileQueue, Log_TotalLine]; line 1 pos 0;
'Filter ('Log_ID = 157456)
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Project [ANNONCE-FNAC-VIGICOLIS-GRX-BIZ-2018hfgr071eyzdtrf2_141001.csv AS Log_FileQueue#290, 5 AS Log_TotalLine#291]
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Not how it works.Try executeBatch.

Comment: thanks thebluephantom; I find a solution to do it:  import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
    import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.query._

    val query = s"""
              |UPDATE Log
              |SET Log_FileQueue = '${newLog_FileIn}', Log_TotalLine= ${NbLine}
              |WHERE Log_ID = 157457;
            """.stripMargin

val config = Config(Map(
  "url"          -> "localhost",
  "databaseName" -> jdbcDatabase,
  "user"         -> jdbcUsername,
  "password"     -> jdbcPassword,
  "queryCustom"  -> query
))


sqlContext.sqlDBQuery(config)

Comment: This is an AZURE approach then?

Comment: yes. This is a way to interact with azure DB or MSSQL DB

Comment: Interesting to know for future reference then. The answer I gave in SPARK sense is also correct.